# What is Bluetooth Smart Ready

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, spp

I am new to Bluetooth technology and I came across this term "Bluetooth Smart Ready". I understand that this term means that both SPP and low energy are supported. But Can anyone help me understand what is it exactly. 
Does Smart Ready refer to a Bluetooth profile like for example SPP or it is some capability of a device?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost answered your own question here:

> I understand that this term means that both SPP and low energy are supported.

In what case would you need a device to support both? A Computer, or mother device which would possibly talk with other devices that may be based on Bluetooth 4.0, such accessories as speakers, headphones, fitness accessories, and even medical tools such as heart-rate monitors and electronic thermometers, etc.

It has got nothing to do with the profile it is configured in, and its more about compatibility.
To put it in simple words, Bluetooth Smart Ready is compatible to communicate with Classic Bluetooth device, Bluetooth Smart device and and Bluetooth Smart Ready device.

On the other hand, A Classic Bluetooth device is able to communicate with other Classic Bluetooth devices and Bluetooth Smart Ready devices.

And, lastly a Bluetooth Smart device can only communicate with Bluetooth Smart and Bluetooth Smart Ready device.

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth Smart and Bluetooth Smart Ready were new branding designations promoted by the Bluetooth SIG for Bluetooth 4.0. That lead to 3 different designations for devices:

- Bluetooth devices - Pre-4.0 devices.
- Bluetooth Smart devices - Basically Bluetooth low energy devices such as peripherals (think heart monitors, fitness equipment, etc.).
- Bluetooth Smart Ready devices - Basically devices that could support both Bluetooth low energy and Bluetooth BR/EDR (Classic Bluetooth).

According to the Bluetooth SIG brand usage guide published May 2016, that terminology has been deprecated.